# Codeigniter session regenerated after browser close

Tags: session, codeigniter-2

I have a situation where by I need to store information into codeigniters session -> be able to close the browser window -> then open up the browser window and for it to recover all the items I stored in a session. I'm aware codeigniter doesn't actually use sessions and instead cookies so this should be really easy.... but it's not.

In FF / Safari / Chrome this works fine but in IE 9 when I close and then re-open the window it regenerates the session id and doesn't pull back the data.

For example this simple code:

```
$this->CI->session->set_userdata('username','My Username');
echo $this->CI->session->userdata('username');
```

when run the first time outputs as expected. I then comment out line 1 and refresh the screen and the session data is again displayed correctely.

Now I close the browser window and open it back up to the same page, again with line 1 commented out. It can't find the session data and the session id is now changed.

I have sessions saving to the database in codeigiter and my session config looks like:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'bcsession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = TRUE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Comment: Of course codeigniter "actually" uses sessions. It can store the session data in a cookie or a database. In the case of a database, you will still have a cookie that contains the ID of the session so it can match it against the database.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set config.php:

$config['sess_expiration'] = write the number of seconds

This is the number of seconds you would like the session to last. The default value is 2 hours (7200 seconds). If you would like a non-expiring session set the value to zero: 0.

**$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;**

Whether to cause the session to expire automatically when the browser window is closed. FALSE is default, but you need to change.

For more, please read in details: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/sessions.html

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution to this in case it effects anyone else.

CI sessions are infact cookies as my logic above however i can't believe I didn't spot it but IE has the setting to delete browser history/cookies/cache upon exit. This was ticket.

Why is it you always look at the most complex reason first and not the most obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `sess_expiration` may require a *non-zero* value to solve your problem. Try that, delete your session in the database table, and give it another shot.

From [Is possible to keep session even after the browser is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684620/is-possible-to-keep-session-even-after-the-browser-is-closed):

Use session_set_cookie_parameters() to give the session cookie a non-zero lifetime before starting the session, or set session.cookie_lifetime to non-zero.

Codeigniter will call that function on `$config['sess_expiration']` so try setting it to a non-zero value.

Comment: "Set to zero for no expiration." from the codeigniter config file comments regarding that parameter.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684620/is-possible-to-keep-session-even-after-the-browser-is-closed

Comment: Yeah 0 means codeigniter sets it to 2 years which I can see correctly in IE's debug tools as correctly working.

I have tried 0 and an actual number though incase it's a bug

Comment: @ChrisG. - so just to check. Codeigniter as far as I can see is storing a session id inside a cookie and also the database. I had thought that because I now have a cookie set it isn't using php style sessions.

From what you're saying thats not right and it is still using a php session and if the php session id doesn't match the cookie session id it rgenerates it?

Comment: I'm actually trying to emulate the issue this guy is having http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359806/why-codeignitor-does-not-finish-the-session-after-closing-the-browser?rq=1

Comment: When you create a session in CI with database sessions enabled, it creates a session ID and stores a row in the sessions table. Then it creates a cookie that contains that session ID so that it can match the cookie to the session in between browser requests.

Comment: CI does not use PHP native sessions afaik. It has its own implementation. `\system\libraries\Session.php`